# how to decode a string containing hexdecimal characters in oracle?

Tags: json, oracle, decode, substr

I wanted to decode metadata field to Persian .
metadata type is CLOB.
For example value  `"\u0646\u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f"` in

```json
{"status":0,"businessId":"2219","condition":"\u0646\u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f","sections":[{"name":"\u062c\u0627\u06cc\u06af\u0627\u0647 \u0627\u0635\u0644\u06cc","uniqid":"5c04018d3e830"}],"Title":"\u0634\u0647\u0631 \u0628\u0627\u0632\u06cc 3","sans":[{"startTime":"08:00:00","endTime":"23:59:00","status":1}]}
```

I use:

```
SELECT UNISTR(replace( DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(metadata,2344,1),'\u','\')) 
  FROM Table;
```

but I get the following error:

```
ORA-30186: '\' must be followed by four hexdecimal characters or another '\'
30186. 00000 -   "'\\' must be followed by four hexdecimal characters or another '\\'"
*Cause:    In the argument of SQL function UNISTR, a '\' must be followed by
           four hexdecimal characters or another '\'
*Action:   Fix the string format
```

what's the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not reproducible in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2dec3d37cd98f55eaf6b0cae2fd5d30f). Also consider to replace `\u` with ```\``` instead of simple `u` as it can be part of the data.

Comment: Thanks, this point helped me, but I still have an error...

Comment: I do not know how to find the error example in the data?